# Bootstrap 4 getting started

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Here's the minimal configuration that I've figured out so far:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="microsoft.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.2/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <script src="bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.2/docs/assets/js/vendor/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.2/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Q: After the opening body tag, what replaces `div class="container"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing replaces it. Bootstrap 4 still uses [containers](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#containers).